# Most significant digit wrong in a dynamically allocated array using the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, fibonacci

i'm doing an assignment, in which I need to use a structure with an int pointer to a number, store n amounts of numbers in the pointer. add two instances of the struct together, and pass those two structures into a Fibonacci sequence function, thus being the first populated struct will be Fibonacci[0], the second populated struct will be Fibonacci[1], and those two added together will be Fibonacci[2], so on and so forth. *A key note* on the assignment is to make sure the dynamically allocated array does not pass a certain value of digits, for example the instructions say to have 50 digits per Fibonacci iteration, in this example I've hard coded

My issue is, I produce a near proper Fibonacci value, however, when I get to Fibonacci[4] my value is 1 digit off in the most significant digit. For the first 3 iterations of Fibonacci I produce the correct value, but from there, I believe it starts using a value that is one digit off, therefore eventually producing totally different numbers than what is expected.

I've fiddled around with my Fibonacci function, however I believe the issue may be within my addFunction, there's an issue with the carry, i'm just stumped at this point, spent all day yesterday only working on Fibonacci summing issues.

```
 #define MAX 3

typedef struct Integer
{
    int *number;

} Integer;

Integer *addFunction(Integer *intA, Integer *intB)
{
    int carry = 0, drop, i;

    if (intA == NULL)
    {
        printf("Null Pointer: intA");
        return NULL;
    }
    if (intB == NULL)
    {
        printf("Null Pointer: intB");
        return NULL;
    }

    Integer *intSum = malloc(sizeof(Integer));
    intSum->number = malloc(sizeof(int));

    for (i=0; i<=2; i++)
    {
        intSum->number[i] = intA->number[i] + intB->number[i] + carry;

        if (intSum->number[i] > 9)
        {
            drop = intSum->number[i] % 10;
            carry = intSum->number[i] / 10;
            intSum->number[i] = drop;
        }
    }

    return intSum;
}

void printFunction(Integer *intC)
{
    int i;

    if (intC == NULL)
    {
        printf("Null Pointer");
        return;
    } 

    for (i=MAX-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        printf("%d", intC->number[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

Integer *loadFirstVariable(int a[])
{
    int i;

    Integer *intA = malloc(sizeof(Integer));
    intA->number = malloc(sizeof(int));

    for (i=0; i<=2; i++)
    {
        intA->number[i] = a[i];
    }

    return intA;
}

Integer *loadSecondVariable(int b[])
{
    int i;

    Integer *intB = malloc(sizeof(Integer));
    intB->number = malloc(sizeof(int));

    for (i=0; i<=2; i++)
    {
        intB->number[i] = b[i];
    }

    return intB;
}

Integer *fibonacci(int n, Integer *first, Integer *second)
{

    int i, y, z;

    Integer *fibSum = malloc(sizeof(Integer));
    fibSum->number = malloc(sizeof(int));

    if (n == 0)
        return first;
    if (n == 1)
        return second;
    if (n >= 2)
    {
        for (i=2; i<=n; i++)
        {
            *fibSum = (*addFunction(first, second));

            for (y=0; y<=2; y++)
            {
                first->number[y] = second->number[y];
                second->number[y] = fibSum->number[y];
            }
        }

        return fibSum;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    int a[3] = {7, 3, 4};
    int b[3] = {2, 9, 5};

    printf("Fibonacci Sequence\n");
    printFunction(fibonacci(4, loadFirstVariable(a), loadSecondVariable(b)));
}
```

Comment: 1) `intB->number = malloc(sizeof(int));` --> `intB->number = malloc(MAX * sizeof(int));`

Comment: 2) Addition of 3 digits may result in 4 digits of result. E.g 999+999=1998

Comment: Seems the first two numbers should be `a[3] = {0, 0, 0};` and `b[3] = {1, 0, 0}` .